# Resurface (or cover) damaged wood door?

Tags: wood, doors, exterior

I have an odd-sized wooden back door.  The outer layers of wood on the lower half of the door are suffering water damage, but the core and inside of the door are fine.

Is there a good way either to resurface (or completely cover) the outside of the door?  Or is it too far gone and should be replaced entirely?

[image: back door]

Answer (score 4):

If you'd rather not replace it and have some time to kill it is possible to re-surface the door.

Door skins are thin veneer sheets meant for this purpose. The difficult part is ensuring the old doors exterior is flat and secure to the frame.

Remove the knob and window frame. Patch and sand the old surface. Glue and nail and bowed/loose sections. Apply contact cement to old door and press new skin in place.

Paint or stain as normal.

Comment: This, except replace the last sentence with, *You're going to need a bigger can of **bondo**.*

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you'll own the house for more than 10 years replace it.  That door is subjected to weathering and a fiberglass door will hold up a lot better and require virtually no maintenance.  It would be a lot of work to repair the damaged door.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the door. It appears to be separating. As it is an exterior door, its purpose  is to make the entrance secure. The strength of the lock depends on the integrity of the door. It looks like you could pry out the window with a screwdriver. If the door frame is in good shape it may be possible to just replace the door.

Comment: Hinges are on the exterior just pop the pins out to remove the door.

Comment: Yup, that is one of the least secure two-lock doors I've ever seen. It's also missing a weather bar… but then again it's also missing a step to elevate it from the rain, so it's just going to happen again unless specific care is paid to the underside after planing to fit… Or get a reinforced UPVC… & either hide the hinges or get un-drillable ones.